# Having issues with printing an array in c

Tags: arrays, c, printf, double

I'm having issues on printing an array, that's what I'm doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM 5

int main () {

    double data[DIM] = {128.5, 131.4, 133.2, 127.1, 130.9};

    printf("%lf", data[DIM]);

    return 0;
}
```

The answer is always 0.000000.

I've also tried to put the values separately, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM 5

int main () {

    double data[DIM];
    data[0]=128.5;
    data[1]=131.4;
    data[2]=133.2;
    data[3]=127.1;
    data[4]=130.9;

    printf("%lf", data[DIM]);

    return 0;
}
```

And still the answer is always 0.000000.

Could someone please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `data[DIM]` is out of bounds. The valid index is in the range 0 to DIM-1

Comment: You can't print an entire array in one step with `printf` - what you do here is actually printing the element beyond the length of the array (undefined behavior).

Comment: OT: `%lf` --> `%f` (i.e. `%f` is sufficent when prnting doubles)

Comment: Use: `for(int i=0;i<DIM;i++) printf("%f ", data[i]);`

Comment: Compile your code with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger and [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 3):

As [4386427](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4386427/4386427) and [500 - Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448932/500-internal-server-error) pointed out, there are two issues at work here.

1. You are trying to print an out-of-bounds index. When you make an array of length 5, indexes go from 0 to 4.
2. More importantly, there is no specific "print array" function that I am aware of. Your best bet is to create a loop that prints each element of the array.

```
void printDoubleArray(double arr[], int length)
{
    printf("[");
    if (length > 0)
    {
        printf("%f", arr[0]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf(", %f", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read all the code. I just saw the `for` loop didn't cover the range

Answer (score 1):

In this call

```
printf("%lf", data[DIM]);
```

you are trying to output a non-existent element of the array with the index `DIM` while the valid range of indices for the array is `[0, DIM)`. This record means that `0` is included in the range as a valid index and `DIM` is excluded from the range.

As a result the call of `printf` invokes undefined behavior.

Also you should use the conversion specifier `f` instead of `lf`. The  length modifier `l` does not have an effect used with the conversion specifier `f`. So it is just redundant.

You can not output a whole array except character arrays (by means of the conversion specifier `s`).

To output the whole array you need to use a loop as for example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < DIM; i++ )
{
    printf( "%.1f ", data[i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM 5

int main(void) 
{
    double data[DIM] = { 128.5, 131.4, 133.2, 127.1, 130.9 };
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < DIM; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%.1f ", data[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
128.5 131.4 133.2 127.1 130.9
```

Comment: 'the valid range of indices for the array is [0, DIM).' no, as you well know:)   It's 0..DIM-1.  Maybe you need more coffee?

Comment: @MartinJames Please look at the record one more. Pay attention to the used delimiters.

Comment: @MartinJames I assume the the syntax used is: `[n` includes `n` and `n)` excludes `n`. So probably `[0, DIM)` is supposed to be the range 0 to DIM-1.

Comment: I was just going to say that readers might not understand the `[0, DIM)` notation style. The other comments speak for themselves. Otherwise, though, I like this answer

Answer (score 0):

C, the language itself, does not have array bounds checking.  You want the element one past the end?  sure thing.  You want the element a million past the end?  sure you can ask for that too (who knows what will happen but you can *ask* for it)

If your compiler supports it, you can get more robust error reporting.  Not C standard but helpful nonetheless.

GCC:
Compile with `-fsanitize=address` and at run-time the sanitizer will catch this overrun:

```
=======================
==220715==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffed8db4988 at pc 0x559ba54babcc bp 0x7ffed8db4920 sp 0x7ffed8db4910
READ of size 8 at 0x7ffed8db4988 thread T0
    #0 0x559ba54babcb in main /tmp/overrun.c:9
```

clang:

In addition to the run-time sanitizer (-fsanitize=address), Clang can also point out your problem at compile time:

```
    printf("%lf", data[DIM]);
                  ^    ~~~
overrun.c:7:5: note: array 'data' declared here
    double data[DIM] = {128.5, 131.4, 133.2, 127.1, 130.9};
    ^
1 warning generated.
```